# I currently have this code to print labels, but now I want to add a loop or function to control how many copies the label prints

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

For this I have a Text Box, that would be the amount of copies that are going to be printed, that is to say if the user puts 2, 2 would be printed and so on.
But I can't figure out how to take the number typed by the user in the textbox and use it in the for condition, I tried to put `For(int i =1;i>1;i++)` before the If but it generates an infinite loop of the print box and still only prints one copy.

I use this code, and the class RawPrinterHelper

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Printing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace Código_zpl
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {            
            string x = "^XA^LH30,30\n^FO20,10^ADN,90,50^AD^FDHello World^FS\n^XZ";
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();                
                    if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
                    {
                   
                        RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName,x);
                   }          
              
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you'd want to put your for loop *inside* the if and wrap it around the SendStringToPrinter call.

Your for loop would look something like `for (int i = 0; i < **userInputVariable**; i++;)`

Comment: @trix I need to replace the name of my text box with "user imput varib"?

Comment: No, that's just a name I gave the variable representing the input received from your text box. I don't see any code for your text box?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much reputation to comment on the conversation between you and Trix. But I would have suggested you created a method that accepts a parameter. that when calling, you can pass the text.

```
void printcopies(int numberofcopies){
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();                
if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
 {
   pd.PrinterSettings.Copies = numberofcopies;
   ....
 }
}
```

....

Comment: Can you explain a little more how to adapt this to my code, I get this error Severity Code Description Project File Line Status suppressed
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'. An explicit conversion already exists (check if you are missing a conversion).

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response.
This error was because copies expects short (int16) not int (Int32). 
See reference - [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.copies?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)

See modification below:
`void printcopies(short numberofcopies){
   PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
   pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();                
   if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
   {
      pd.PrinterSettings.Copies = numberofcopies;
      ....
   }
 }`